# PHP: Is_numeric returns false on 0

Tags: php, regex, integer, numerical, numeric

`Is_numeric()` as well as `is_int()` returns false if the value is 0. What can i do instead to verify that a specific value is numbers only in PHP?

Are we heading straight for the Regular Expressions camp, or are there some nice, handy feature for this out there already?

Thanks!

Comment: no repro, `is_numeric(0)` returns `bool(true)` for me. the same with `is_int`

Comment: @Industrial: Are you sure? http://www.ideone.com/h5CSa

Comment: You sure it's not a the letter O instead of a zero?

Comment: I get true on both if I use $var = 0; -- Mind posting some code?

Comment: Possibly related... different language but similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691199/c-parse-string-0-to-integer/691278#691278

Comment: @Industrial: What version of PHP are you using? Some older versions might be incorrectly returning false.

Comment: Thanks for voting me down. I have of course verified that it is a 0(zero) first.

Comment: Restarted PHP on the server and it works out well now. Have no idea of why it occored though. Thanks everybody for their help!

Answer (score 7):

It is returning true for me in both cases:

```
var_dump(is_numeric(0));
var_dump(is_int(0));
```

**Result:**

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Comment: Very strange. Have no idea of why my test (windows) environment does return false.

Answer (score 7):

Zero, as an integer is empty.
So ensure that there is no check for empty before you check for Is_numeric() or is_int()

Comment: Thanks!

surprisingly that's exactly what I was doing! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump(is_int("0"));
```

Will pass false because you are passing it the zero as a string literal.  You could try passing the same thing as a variable which has gone through (I believe) parseInt("");

Though my php may be a little off, having been Javascripting nonstop the last week or two.

Comment: Hi! The string isn't being passed as a string.

Comment: @Industrial that's a paradox ;)

Comment: @Gordon Duuh. That was one for the wall of fame definitely. The value that is passed were not a string, but only a number. I'll hope that made it understandable ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with REQUEST is better check the input first by using filter_input. Here is an example check 'id' from $_GET.

```
filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)
```

the full example

```
if (is_int(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
        die('please input a integer');
}
```

Well, the feature come up with version PHP >= 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I struggeled on the same problem, and it happenned that there was a space after the number.

Long Story short, what ever the number is:

```
is_numeric(" 0.0") --> YES
is_numeric("0.0 ") --> NO
```

Here is an example...

```
public function getCoordinates()
{
    return sprintf('%1$f , %2$f',$this->getLatitude(),$this->getLongitude());
}
```

Later in the process...

```
        $myarr = explode(",",$_ScreenCoordinates);
        echo "_ScreenCoordinates:$_ScreenCoordinates<br>";
        echo "myarr[0]:".$myarr[0]." - ".((is_numeric($myarr[0]))?"YES":"NO")."<br>";
        echo "myarr[1]:".$myarr[1]." - ".((is_numeric($myarr[1]))?"YES":"NO")."<br>";
        echo "trimmed[0]:".$myarr[0]." - ".((is_numeric(trim($myarr[0])))?"YES":"NO")."<br>";
```

Printed on screen:

```
Array ( [0] => 1.200000 [1] => 123.456000 )
_ScreenCoordinates:1.200000 , 123.456000
myarr[0]:*1.200000 * - NO
myarr[1]:* 123.456000* - YES
trimmed[0]:*1.200000 * - YES
```

Answer (score 0):

This also can happen if this `0` is a boolean `FALSE` in fact.
`is_numeric()` always returns `FALSE` for boolean.

Answer (score -1):

```
if($price != 0) {
    if(is_numeric($price)) {
        $price = $price; // numeric
    } else { // is not numeric }
} else {
    $price = $price; // 0 as numeric
}
```

Comment: Format your answer properly and you really don't need to answer a 7 year old question which happens to have an accepted answer.

Comment: Not only does this answer make no sense, there's a syntax error to boot.