# Getting MySQL record count with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I would like to know how can I get record count of a query with C#.

Here is the code that I use..

```
    MySqlDataReader recordset = null;
    query = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY type_ID ASC", this.conn);
    recordset = query.ExecuteReader();


    while (recordset.Read())
    {
        result.Add(recordset["type_ID"].ToString());

    }
    return result;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was using a `SELECT COUNT(*)` and expected an `int` to be returned.  You may need this to get a usable value:

```
mysqlint = int.Parse(query.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Answer (score 6):

A couple of things...

The SQL statement you would use is:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test

However, when using the **MySQL Connector/Net** to connect to MySQL through C# there is some care to be given when handling query results.

For example, as cited in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691199/c-sharp-parse-string-0-to-integer) and on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/253265/int32-parse-fails-to-convert-the-string-0-zero-on-some-systems) `int.Parse("0")` equivalently known as `Int32.Parse("0")` can throw a `FormatException` on some machines.

I have found that `Convert.ToInt32` handles this case nicely.

So your code will be something like this:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(cs))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test", conn))
    {
         int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
         return count;
    }
}
```

Remember to make use of **using statements** in order to ensure that the MySQL objects get disposed of properly.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding a new element in `result` for each row. Depending on the type of `result` you should be able to do something like `result.Count` after the while loop completes.

Comment: @she hates me: Just curious, but why why would you need the row count before the loop?

Comment: @she hates me: If the result set is small, iterate through it once and store the rows in a list, then get the count, then iterate through the stored list to get all the rows again. The second time you iterate through you know how many elements you have and you can do whatever you were doing that needs the count here.

Answer (score 1):

You could run another query first to get the count :

```
query = new MySqlCommand("SELECT count(*) as theCount FROM test ORDER BY type_ID ASC", this.conn);
```

but in truth, you are probably best changing the problem so you wont need the count until after you have populated the list.

Comment: You shouldn't run more queries than you need to.  Doing so will make the application run a bit more slowly.  You can do this with one query.