# Getting count of rows from MySQL database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to count the number of rows in a MySql database and return the result in a label.

This is my code:

```
string connection = "SERVER= ###; PORT=###; DATABASE=###; UID=###; PASSWORD=###; CharSet=utf8;";

MySqlConnection mySqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connection);
MySqlCommand mySqlCmd = mySqlCon.CreateCommand();


mySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select count(*) as myCount from ###.###";
mySqlCon.Open();

int returnValue = (int) mySqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();

lblCLientNumber.Text = returnValue.ToString();
```

The error I get is: 
`Specified cast is not valid.`

But when I run the SQL command in phpMyAdmin the result is accurate.

I'm not sure where am I making a mistake.

Comment: What is the output of `Console.WriteLine(typeof(mySqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
returnValue = int.Parse(mySqlCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

C# Is asking for an integer;

Take a look here [Getting MySQL record count with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807282/getting-mysql-record-count-with-c-sharp)
this question has been asked before

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because *ExecuteScalar* function returns an object.

You could do the following:

```
int returnValue = int.Parse(mySqlCmd.ExecuteScalar().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(mySqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

However, my preference would be to reference the field.  For example something like

```
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select count(*) as myCount from 
###.###", connection))
{
    using(MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if(rdr.Read()) 
        {
            returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["myCount"]);
        }
    }
    rdr.Close();
}
```